# Permissions protectionLevel wrong?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-package-managers, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to adapt my code for Android Marshmallow.

I wrote a function to check if a permission is revocable or not (`PROTECTION_NORMAL` and `PROTECTION_SIGNATURE` are granted upon install).

Running on API-22, `Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` returns `protectionLevel=PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS`, which [is what I expected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE).

But on API-22, `Manifest.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` also returns `protectionLevel=PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS`, which [is wrong from the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INSTALL_SHORTCUT).

**How does that happen?
What's wrong with my code:**

```
final PermissionInfo permissionInfo = packageManager.getPermissionInfo(permission, 0);
switch (permissionInfo.protectionLevel) {
    case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_NORMAL:
    case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_SIGNATURE:
        return false;
    default:
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Manifest.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT also returns protectionLevel=PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS

Not if you are using the code you show in your question. At best, your code is indicating if the `protectionLevel` is `normal` or `signature` and has no other bits set.

> How does that happen?

`protectionLevel` is a bitmask. You are not comparing the bitmask properly.

```
int coreBits=info.protectionLevel & PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_MASK_BASE;
```

`coreBits` will be one of the core `PROTECTION_` values. `protectionLevel` may not, as there may be higher-order bits set (e.g., `PROTECTION_FLAG_PRE23`). And, on Android 6.0, `coreBits` reports that `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` is a `normal` permission.

See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/PermissionReporter) for a demonstration of using `PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_MASK_BASE`.

Comment: Awesome answer. Did not catch that `protectionLevel` was a bitmask. Thanks for the reference code too https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Permissions/PermissionReporter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/permreporter/MainActivity.java